# image in UIImageView sticks to the bottom of the UIImage space

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm having and issue and i would like to know if doing this is possible.

I have a UIImageView with the content mode of .aspectFit, the green part is the UIImageView background color and the image inside is the actual image, i want to know if it's possible to make the image inside the UIImageView sticks to the bottom and not just float in the center of the UIImageView space.

**Note**: Depending on a parameter i'll have to change the UIImageView height dynamically to make the items look bigger or smaller

The photo below represents the problem description.

[image: UIimge]

Comment: try in storyBoard -> ur imageView -> contentmode -> Bottom

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you may want to change your `UIImageView`'s `Content Mode` to `Bottom`,

```
imageView.contentMode = .bottom
```

[image: image content mode]

Comment: when i do that the image losses the aspect fit proportion and it just doesn't look good, i would like to have aspect fit but attached to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Put your `UIImageView` to `UIView` and then anchor image view (with content mode *aspect fit*) to the bottom of its superview. Also set height of ImageView equal to height of View in certain ratio

[image]

Then if you need to change height of ImageView, just change aspect ratio of heights.

Comment: the thing is that i'll need to change the height of the UIImage view dynamically depending on a parameter so if i do that i won't be able to achieve that

Comment: do you need to change the whole size of view with green background color or just size of image?

Comment: I tried just the way you mention it, but I'm still getting the same result. by the way the image is png, I don't know if that affects in a way https://imgur.com/a/bH3bM7F

Comment: @Barcenas it shouldn’t, But I’m not sure. What is problem exactly?

Comment: This is the thing, i have a shelf that has products on it, the problem is that the products aren't laying on the shelf they are floating and that looks wierd to the user, so i want to make the product(image) touch the bottom of the UIImageView space in order to make the product look that is actually standing on the shelf and not just floating. look at this image https://imgur.com/a/TvLc7Yt

Comment: @Barcenas set top constraint to bigger value

Comment: i know, but if i do that it wouldn't look good in a smaller phone, like an iphone 5s or something, the thing is that i want to have it dynamically and not checking which phone the user has to change the top value,

Comment: @Barcenas Doesnt it depend on constraints of ImageView’s superview?

Comment: @Barcenas Wait, try to remove top constraint.

Comment: @Barcenas check my edited answer where I used equal heights.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting UIEdgeInsets ?

`UIImageView.image = UIImage(yourImage.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: -10)`